# Building charts with the inverse function theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Let $ S^2 $ denote the $ 2 $-sphere in $ \mathbb R^3 $ and define a the usual spherical coordinates $ \chi\colon \left]0,\pi\right[\times \left]0,2\pi\right[\to S^2 $ as
$$
\chi(\phi,\theta) = \begin{pmatrix}\sin\phi \cos\theta\\ \sin\phi \sin\theta\\ \cos\phi\end{pmatrix}
$$
for varying $ \phi\in \left]0,\pi\right[ $ and $ \theta\in \left]0,2\pi\right[ $.

I want to show that $ \chi $ gives in some way a chart for $ S^2 $, i.e. a homeomorphism between an open set of $ S^2 $ and some open subset of $ \mathbb R^2 $.

The book I am reading suggests the use of the inverse function theorem for this task, but it's not entirely clear to me what the author is doing.

The Jacobian matrix of $ \chi $ at the point $ (\phi,\theta) $ is
$$
\chi^\prime(\phi,\theta) =
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\phi \cos\theta & -\sin\phi \sin\theta\\
\cos\phi \sin\theta & \sin\phi \cos\theta\\
-\sin\phi & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and I's immediate to check that at least one of its $ 2 $-minors is nonzero. Suppose
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
\cos\phi_0 \cos\theta_0 & -\sin\phi_0 \sin\theta_0\\
\cos\phi_0 \sin\theta_0 & \sin\phi \cos\theta_0
\end{vmatrix}
\neq 0
$$
for some $ (\phi_0,\theta_0) $. Then the new map
$$
\tilde\chi\colon \left]0,\pi\right[\times \left]0,2\pi\right[\times \mathbb R\text{,}\qquad \tilde\chi(\phi\theta,t) = \begin{pmatrix}\sin\phi \cos\theta\\ \sin\phi \sin\theta\\ \cos\phi + t \end{pmatrix}
$$
has nonzero Jacobian determinant at $ (\phi_0,\theta_0,0) $, and thus there are open sets $ (\phi_0,\theta_0)\in V\subset \left]0,\pi\right[\times \left]0,2\pi\right[ $ and $ \chi(\phi_0,\theta_0)\in W\subset \mathbb R^3 $ such that the restriction
$$
\tilde \chi\colon V\to W
$$
is a diffeomorphism.

I see that in this way we can obtain a *homeomorphism* between an open subset of $ \left]0,\pi\right[\times \left]0,2\pi\right[ $ and a subset of $ S^2 $.

But at this point the author write something I find confusing, i.e. that

> Had we not known in
> advance that $ \chi\colon \left]0, π\right[ × \left]0, 2\pi\right[ \to \mathbb R^3 $ is one-to-one, this would in no way follow from what we have done with the Inverse Function Theorem, which guarantees invertibility only near a point where the Jacobian is nonsingular.
>
> Of course, since we do know that χ is one-to-one on $ \left]0, π\right[ × \left]0, 2\pi\right[ $ our arguments show that its inverse is smooth (a map on $ S^2 $ is smooth, by definition, if it is smooth on some open set about each point).

I don't see why the one-to-one condition is so fundamental. Why is it so?

Comment: The inverse function theorem guarantees local diffeomorphism, but it does not guarantee a global injection. This is exactly what the book is trying to say. You need to know the global injection from somewhere else. Think of a smooth covering space, it satisfies the inverse function theorem. You have local diffeomorphism everywhere, but globally it is not one-to-one.